# Can someone explain this to me why i keep getting it in once code only:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: C.<init>(I)V

Tags: java, constructor

I am new to Java Programming..
I created 2 Projects(inheritance and constructors)
When i create a class(one different class for each project) and run the following code:

```
public class class4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("This is the main class");
        C obj_1 = new C(5);
    }
}

class C
{
    int i, j;

    C(int z) //Defining a constructor
    {   
        i = z;
        j = i;
        System.out.println(" value  is " + j);
    }
}
```

It gives me following error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: C.<init>(I)V at class4.main(class4.java:6)` when i try to run it in my "Inhertiance" project and runs fine when i try to run it in the "constructor Project".

P.S : The inheritance project has 2 more classes as well but none with a class name `C` and object name `obj_1`.
Can anyone please explain ?

Comment: your code works just fine.

Comment: @Abhishek_04 have  you saved your class C and class4 to the same folder? also please follow the naming convention of java http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: @Abhishek_04 hows it going? good luck reading I'm at my chapter 13 of my bought book and probably be using swing component because chapter 14 will be talking about swing component

Comment: @Abhishek_04 also after finishing the book you might want to read also about MySQL it serves as a storage of important e.g. player money value etc.

Comment: @Abhishek_04 after reading MySQL storage you might want to try Blender 3d multimedia system if you want to create some games using java

Comment: @abcOfJava ..I just learnt how to install and use eclipse from a youtube video,and since then using the book.
I got away with the problem by simple deleting the  "inheritance" project and then recreating the new project by the same name and then creating the class and pasting the above code.
Your link for naming convention in java has been useful.Thanks

Comment: Hi @abcOfJava ..Thanks a lot for all of your information.Much appreciated.(I am a former Data scientist,learning JAVA to be more original at my work.)